# How to make directshow an OpenMAX compliant

Tags: directshow, openmax

Can anybody please tell me how can i make directshow an OpenMAX compliant ? If i use directshow then it will not provide me the media infrastructure portability. I have to do something in the integration layer of openMAX this thing i know!! please provided any source which can help.

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this is a start?](http://www.khronos.org/files/openmax/whitepapers/OpenMAX_IL_Dshow_Filter_integration.pdf) It is a draft about integrating DirectShow filters in OpenMAX.